# Can't execute init scripts on remote host via ssh

Tags: ssh

I'm on a `Cent 5.10` host.

I am issuing remote commands to this host to start services, every service reads as a success for starting:

```
kkahn@host: /home/kkahn$ ssh -q -t host.example.com "sudo /etc/init.d/redacted-service start "
Starting service
Service started
Connection to host.example.com closed.
```

The PID file is even created under `/var/run` with a PID entry, but there is no process started! If I run the command with a `sleep 10` at the end it will run the process on the remote host for 10 seconds and stop when the command has ended.

Comment: If you ssh to the server (interactive session) and then manually start the service and then logout, do you have the same issue?

Comment: Nope! This is only when running the start commands remotely.

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I did, but they are not logging anything useful. I don't see messages even showing the process at all. It just shows my ssh connection. I don't know what to turn up to increase any verbosity.

Comment: "I don't see messages even showing the process at all" => This is highly suspicious. Are you using systemd for your services? If so, see what `journalctl` displays.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 5.10.

Comment: Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments (host and tsrget).

Comment: With no log and without knowing the exact inner working of `redacted-service`, we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `sudo -i` and checking the output of `set` on both a host that doesn't work and one that does (a Cent5 box compared to Cent6), I noticed the following:

```
[root@cent5-node ~]# set | grep -i sudo
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=100100017
SUDO_UID=100100017
SUDO_USER=kkahn

[root@cent6-node ~]# set | grep -i sudo
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1001000173
SUDO_UID=1001000173
SUDO_USER=kkahn
[root@testcentsix(testcentsix) ~]#
```

My `SUDO_GID` and `SUDO_UID` are correct on `cent6-node` - and **shortened** on `cent5-node`! On Cent5 the IDs have the `3` removed.

As it turns out, this is something that was patched in later releases of `sudo`:

https://gratisoft.us/sudo/changes.html

> ```
>     * plugins/sudoers/env.c, plugins/sudoers/ldap.c:
>     Use MAX_UID_T_LEN + 1 for uid/gid buffers, not MAX_UID_T_LEN to
>     prevent potential truncation. Bug #562.
>     [29d9fc4e0c4e]
> ```

The version of `sudo` running on these Cent5 hosts is `1.7.2p1`, whereas our Cent6 hosts have `1.8.6p3`. After looking through the source code of `1.7.2p1`, I sure enough found:

> ```
> ...
> char idbuf[MAX_UID_T_LEN];
> ...
> ```

After installing a later version of `sudo` on the Cent5 node, this problem has been resolved.